# Create a decent unsubscribe method

Tags: html, unsubscribe

I've been asked to create a system to send newsletters. A HTML template has been created by an external company. I've got the sourcecode so i can alter it. One thing that was missing was an unsubscribe method. I would like to add a method so that when people click on the link they get an message that they can sent. I would like to process these unsubscriptions automatically but there lies my problem. How can i be sure which user this is? Because if i look at the sender emailadress i can't be 100% sure it is this person. So my question is whether i can incorporate a unique id in the mail and how can i get that unique id in the unsubscribe email? 
I've got a system working that can upload the HTML page to a mail and send it. That part works. The email is send to whatever address is in the database in BCC.
Do I need to send each email separately?
Can anyone help me?

Here you can find the unsubscribe link:

```
Wenst u deze nieuwsbrief niet meer te ontvangen? Schrijf u hier uit <strong><a href="mailto:info@odbeeck.be?subject=Gelieve mij uit te schrijven" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">info@odbeeck.be</a></strong>
```

Some where in this code i would like to have a unique id so that when i process the email i know which user in the database it represents.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thnx,

Answer (score 1):

If you process it automatically i would propose to add a http://yourdomain.com/unsubscribe?id=abcdef link to the newsletter for unsubscribing. It's mostly done like this, so the user expects it to work like this and it's easy to pass the id parameter.

Other topic: The id should not be passed directly, create a hash over it and use that one for identifying.

You need to send each mail separately. For adding the unique id to each mail you need some templating mechanism or some custom written script.

Comment: So you mean create a single HTML page that handles the unsubscription? But how do i know wich user it is?

Comment: The ID associated with the user is passed into the URL as shown above, then you just check your database for that ID and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is whether i can incorporate a unique id in the mail and how can i get that unique id in the unsubscribe email?

Yes.

> The email is send to whatever address is in the database in BCC. Do I need to send each email separately?

Yes.

Generate the unique (preferably random and definitely not sequential) id. Store it in a database next to the email address. When the link is clicked look up the email address the id is associated with and unsubscribe using that information.

---

That said, you would probably be better off outsourcing this to a third party with experience in sending bulk emailing. That will minimise the load on your mail servers and reduce the chance of a screw up causing your mail servers being marked as a source of spam in the various RTBLs.

Comment: Yes the unique id i understand but how do i get it in the html template? Right now i'm thinking of creating the html page that contains the newsletter and at the moment we want to send i just import it into a mail. How do i get this unique link in there?  I agree that a third party would be best but it is only once every 3 months that we will send the newsletter and only to a select few customers (<100)

Comment: You send the email using the programming language of your choice instead of manually.